# Internet connection suddenly stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, internet

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and my internet suddenly stopped working. It is not an issue with the internet connect per se, since I get a very connection on my other devices. I also see the network in Linux, and I can change its settings. The nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` is 127.0.0.53, and I can ping that. However, in network settings both Default Route and DNS are different: 192.168.1.1, and I can't ping that. Now, 192.168.1.1 is the address of my router, and I can log into that from my MacBook, but not from Ubuntu. Actually, if I log into the router, it tells me that my Linux box is connected to it. I have not changed any router settings, and I also restarted it, just in case.

I just tried to ping [www.google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk) on Ubuntu, and that either does not work or gives extremely long response times. I simply do not get a stable connection on Ubuntu (it came back briefly, but now it's back down).

Comment: I actually have the suspicion that this might be connected to the dual-boot issues I'm having. Is it possible that (even when I boot into Ubuntu) windows is running in the background and blocking the network adapter?

Comment: Windows has nothing to do with this.  When using Ubuntu, windows is completely shutdown.  If Windows on same box can connect okay, imagine last Ubuntu update did something.

Comment: It's working again after I did the following: I booted windows and started a browser. This complained about a network change being detected, but then connected fine. When I re-booted into Linux after that my connection was back. Really odd.

Comment: "When using Ubuntu, windows is completely shutdown."  Not really: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the issue is. I had plugged in a second monitor, which is connected through a KVN switch. If I use that switch to suppress the output from my Linux machine (i.e. the monitor shows the output of my MacBook), for some bizarre reason the signal on the line seems to interfere with the wifi. The computer still sees the wifi network and the router, though.